# How can I refactor this code and apply OO patterns?

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

I have four `RichTable` instances in my class and there is a notion of `current` table instance  . Depending on a flag `resetAll` I need to clear out selections of either all the tables or all tables **except the current one** . If `resetAll` is true then clear out everything , otherwise leave out the current one . The index of the current table is passed as a parameter to the method that does the clean up action.

The call for clearing out everything looks like this :

```
clearSubTypeSettings(true,-1);
```

The call for clearing all but the current one looks like this :

```
clearSubTypeSettings(true, col);
```

The implementation of the above method is this :

```
private void clearSubTypeSettings(boolean resetAll, int exceptControl) {
    if (!resetAll) {
        clearAllExceptCurrent(exceptControl);
    } else {
        clearAll();
    }
 }
```

Now these two methods `clearAllExceptCurrent(exceptControl)` and  `clearAll()` look almost the same . Here are the implementations :

```
  private void clearAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SUBTYPE_TABLES; i++)
            if (getSubTypeTable(i).getSelectedRowKeys() != null) {
                RichTable richTable = getSubTypeTable(i);
                RowKeySet rowkeySet = richTable.getSelectedRowKeys();
                rowkeySet.clear();
                AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(richTable);
            }
    }
```

And

```
private void clearAllExceptCurrent(int exceptControl) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SUBTYPE_TABLES; i++)
        if (i != exceptControl && getSubTypeTable(i).getSelectedRowKeys() != null) {
            RichTable richTable = getSubTypeTable(i);
            RowKeySet rowkeySet = richTable.getSelectedRowKeys();
            rowkeySet.clear();
            AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(richTable);
        }
}
```

I feel like I am writing duplicate redundant code here and will complicate maintenance in future . How can I improve this code and make it more object oriented  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let `clearAll()` **delegate** (=> OOP pattern) to `clearAllExceptCurrent()` (=> improve code by removing duplicated code, make it more maintainable):

```
private void clearAll() {
   clearAllExceptCurrent(-1);
}
```

The only difference between your two methods is the condition `i != exceptControl` in `clearAllExceptCurrent()`. By passing `-1` this condition is always `true` and therefore effectively non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of the repeated code is the bit that clears the table.  So how about:

```
private void clearTable(int id) {
    if (getSubTypeTable(i).getSelectedRowKeys() != null) {
        RichTable richTable = getSubTypeTable(i);
        RowKeySet rowkeySet = richTable.getSelectedRowKeys();
        rowkeySet.clear();
        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(richTable);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
 private void clearAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < SUBTYPE_TABLES; i++) {
        clearTable(i);
    }
 }

private void clearAllExceptCurrent(int exceptControl) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SUBTYPE_TABLES; i++) {
        if (i != exceptControl) {
            clearTable(i)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Moved `if` statement inside `clearTable`